# ImageResizer vs. Azure Files

Tags: imageresizer, azure-files

I have an Azure web app that have ImageResizer installed.

Using the azurereader2 plugin (https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/azurereader2) I can scale images place in an **Azure Blob Storage**.

But I also have files places on **Azure Files** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-introduction)

How can I get ImageResizer to scale them as well?

Answer (score 0):

Mount the SMB share as a virtual folder in IIS. It can act just like a network drive.

Comment: Great solution, but I the website is hosted in an Azure web app - i'll update the question

Comment: If you can't access IIS, you may want to copy/paste/modify AzureReader2 to use the Files api: https://www.francoisdelport.com/2015/07/using-azure-file-service-part-3/